# Classification of data

Tags: python, mysql, classification

We have a table of 10000 records of unclassified data, I would like to classify them based on certain properties like text similarity or certain features.

For Example, 
Consider that a single column contains names, phone numbers and gender

Now I have a index which has single entity names, phone numbers, email. I want to tag the columns with a the index ids of appropriate types

Table A (Column Table)

```
id      column_data     index_id
1       abc             
2       male            
3       +1298312123     
4       pqr             
5       +1283711231     
6       female         
7       +1231231112     
8       male            
9       xyz
```

Table B (Index Table)

```
id      index_name
1       name
2       phone number
3       email
```

So, I want to tag all names, phone numbers and gender with the single index_id for easy identification of data.

P.S I have used the data as a demonstration, We have thousands of data and 1000's of index that we would like to classify?

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: unless you are going to apply machine learning here, you should write down all the rules for classification, and loop through the data.... what have you tried so far?

Comment: We have tried string comparison. However, integrity of data could not be verified after a certain extent. We used Jaro Winkler Algorithm for string comparison.

Comment: So use machine learning, give it a bunch of examples and the correct classification so it can learn the rules on how to classify with high success rates

Comment: Ok. Great. I have not tried on machine learning yet. Are there any suggestions where to start with? Also, I assume that they would run on rule set? Mostly string comparison in our case.

Comment: No rule set, i will write a detailed answer to explain

Comment: In this hypothetical data set, are records 8 and 9 related? Either way, how can we tell?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is machine-learning classifiers.

Basically in classifiers, you create your model (there are many tutorials on that, I would start [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/)) and then train it with data. The data you train on should be of correct classifications so it can learn how to deal even with new forms of data that it hasn't encountered before and make "the best guess" possible. (In machine-learning lingo, that's called making a prediction)

Just so you know what to google, look for examples of multi-class classification, and my best advice is to start with `tensorflow` for python (the link above is to tutorials for tensorflow).

If you are unfamiliar with machine-learning principles, i would suggest to start with the basics of machine learning so you understand what you're doing first.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This is a fair start. Let me try that on and get back to you. Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some data tagged with the index values for column data for training, you can create character n-grams for the column data and train a classifier.

Comment: Ok. I am not sure if I completely understood the n-grams thing. Let me get an idea on what it actually is. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers that bring up tensorflow and n-grams are overshooting, since it seems like all you want to do is transfer the index_name id from one dataframe to another. There are a few ways to do that, but one of them might look like this, using regex, for better or worse:

```
import re

for index, row in tableA.iterrows():
    if tableA.loc[index, 'column_data'] == 'male' or tableA.loc[index, 'column_data'] == 'female':
        tableA.loc[index, 'index_id'] = ##whatever index number you've assigned for gender, which doesn't appear in your dataframe
    elif re.search(r'\W*', str(tableA.loc[index, 'column_data'])): #matches all non-word characters
        tableA.loc[index, 'index_id'] = 2
    else:
        tableA.loc[index, 'index_id'] = 1
```

Answer (score -3):

UPDATE TableA SET index_id=(CASE WHEN column_data REGEXP '[0-9]' THEN 2 WHEN column_data ='male' OR column_data ='female' THEN 4 ELSE 1 END)

Use regular expression for email also